# Combining a selection-rectangle with zoom + pan in a D3.js 4.x Force Simulation

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I've built a Force Simulation in D3.js 4.4 that uses the built in zoom + pan functions (`d3.zoom()`), combined with a selection-rectangle for selecting nodes (like [here](http://bl.ocks.org/paradite/71869a0f30592ade5246) or [here](http://bl.ocks.org/lgersman/5311083)).

Dragging/panning the viewport around is the default behaviour, but is filtered out when the Shift-key is held. Then another drag-handler takes over and draws a rectangle from the starting point. On mouseup the code intersects the rectangle with the nodes on screen and selects them.

This all works fine, but the whole thing goes sideways when I apply zoom behavior to the equation. I've pinpointed the problem to the `scale` values `d3.event.transform` applies to the g-container that contains the nodes.

Due to the nature of this project (and the internet-less dev environment we're working in) I can't copy/paste the working code on the web. So here are the abridged parts that are causing the problem (I had to re-type these from another monitor).

```
var currentZoom = null;

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.5, 10])
    .filter(function() {
        return !d3.event.shiftKey // Don't zoom/pan when shift is pressed
    })
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
    currentZoom = d3.event.transform;

    d3.select("g.links").attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
    d3.select("g.nodes").attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
}

// This fires on mouseup after dragging the rectangle (svg rect)
function intersectSelectionRect() {
    var rect = svg.select("rect.selection-rect");

    // Intersect rectangle with nodes
    var lx = parseInt(rect.attr("x"));
    var ly = parseInt(rect.attr("y"));
    var lw = parseInt(rect.attr("width"));
    var lh = parseInt(rect.attr("height"));

    // Account for zoom
    if (!!currentZoom) {
        // Recalculate for pan
        lx -= currentZoom.x;
        ly -= currentZoom.y;

        // Recalculate for zoom (scale)
        // currentZoom.k ???????????????
    }

    // Rectangle corners
    var upperRight = [lx + lw, ly];
    var lowerLeft = [lx + ly + lh];

    nodes.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if ((item.x < upperRight[0] && item.x > lowerLeft[0]) &&
            (item.y > upperRight[1] && item.y < lowerLeft[1])) {
            item.selected = true;
        }
    });
}
```

As you can (hopefully) make out, the problem occurs when recalculating the rect x and y with the zoom k (scale). If the scale is 1 (starting value) the recalculation is correct. If it's anything other than that the actual selection rectangle no longer matches the one drawn on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is setup properly you should be able to [apply](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/blob/master/README.md#transform_apply) the transform to the points,

```
var upperRight = [lx, ly];
var lowerLeft = [lx + lw, ly + lh];

if (!!currentZoom) {
  upperRight = currentZoom.apply(upperRight);
  lowerLeft = currentZoom.apply(lowerLeft);
}
```

Comment: Gonna mark this as the answer even though I can't get it to work right now. It's probably the way this should be implemented.

Comment: @Some_Guy you will need to post am [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for a better answer. I will say, that storing the `currentZoom` is not the correct way to do it, rather you should grab the state from the node that the zoom is applied on through `d3.zoomTransform(selection.node())`